# Forma correcta o la mejor manera de colocar ImagenView o Button por encima de de una imagen respetando su posicion

Tags: android-studio, xml

Estoy intentando poner botones y alguna que otra imagen por encima de una imagen para lo cual quiero que se mantengan en su posición a lo cual use un **ConstraintLayout** pensando que de esa manera se mantendrán siempre en el mismo lugar pero

A la hora de probarla se muestran algunos mas abajo y otros correctos, mi intención es que tal como se muestra en el editor de **android studio** se muestre en los telefonos

intento realizar algo parecido a lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi XML es el siguiente

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Fragments.RegistrarDolorFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_cuerpo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cuerpohumano"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/temporal"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_cuerpo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view_cuerpo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.36"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view_cuerpo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nameUser"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.515" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pruebaImage"
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_redondo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.281" />

    <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/temporal2"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_cuerpo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view_cuerpo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.678"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view_cuerpo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nameUser"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.515" />

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Por ejemplo a tu ImagenView le debes definir los margenes a los que se va a ubicar:

```
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
```

Comment: Si le agrego los margin a los 4 lados con tal de que quede pero cada ves que lo pruebo en el movil, aparece un poco mas arriba.. cuando en el edtior segun se muestra bien

Comment: Estube probando un poco elimine todos los layout_constraint... los agregue otra ves y parece funcionar por lo mientras en un elemento.. probare lo mismo con los demás **ImageView** y **Button** para ver si funciona con eso para mantenerlos en su posición y se vea igual en todos los dispositivos o en la mayoría.

Comment: No funciono para los demas elementos, por alguna razon en el editor de **Android Studio** se ven de una forma pero al instalarlo se muestran de otra forma.